# Finding a cryptoarithmetic solution

Tags: lisp, cryptography, common-lisp

This code is intended to find all possible solutions to a cryptoarithmetic problem.  The description of the problem I was trying to solve is here:

> In cryptoarithmetic problems, we are given a problem wherein the
>   digits are replaced with characters representing digits. A solution to
>   such a problem is a set of digits that, when substituted in the
>   problem, gives a true numerical interpretation.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> IS
> IT
> ___
> OK
> ```
>
> has a solution
>
> ```
> { I = 1; K = 1; O = 3; S = 5; T = 6}
> ```
>
> For each of the below cryptoarithmetic problems, write a program that finds all
>   the solutions in the shortest possible time.
>
> ```
> IS     I
> IT    AM
> __    __
> OK    OK
> ```

I was only able to solve it using brute force, though I believe there are more efficient methods.  I am also hoping to receive feedback on my formatting, naming, and really anything you think could use improvement.

```
(defun place-value-to-integer (the-list &OPTIONAL place-value) 
  (let ((place-value (if place-value place-value 1))) 
    (if (= (length the-list) 1) (* place-value (first the-list))
      (+ (* place-value (first (last the-list))) (place-value-to-integer (butlast the-list) (* 10 place-value))))))

(defun fill-from-formula (formula guess)
  (loop for digit in formula collect (gethash digit guess)))

(defun check-answer (augend-formula addend-formula sum-formula guess)
  (let ((augend (fill-from-formula augend-formula guess))
    (addend (fill-from-formula addend-formula guess))
    (sum (fill-from-formula sum-formula guess)))
        (= (place-value-to-integer sum) (+ (place-value-to-integer augend) (place-value-to-integer addend)))))

(defun brute-force-guess(augend-formula addend-formula sum-formula unique-values &OPTIONAL callback guess) 
  (let ((guess (if (null guess) (make-hash-table) guess)))
    (loop for digit in '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do 
      (setf (gethash (car unique-values) guess) digit) 
      (if (= (length unique-values) 1) 
        (if (check-answer augend-formula addend-formula sum-formula guess) (print-result augend-formula addend-formula sum-formula guess) nil)
        (brute-force-guess augend-formula addend-formula sum-formula (cdr unique-values) callback guess)))))

(defun print-result (augend-formula addend-formula sum-formula guess) 
  (format t "One answer is ~a + ~a = ~a ~%" 
      (fill-from-formula augend-formula guess)
      (fill-from-formula addend-formula guess)
      (fill-from-formula sum-formula guess)))

(defun find-unique-values (the-list) 
  (let ((unique-items ())) 
    (loop for sublist in the-list do 
      (loop for item in sublist do
          (unless (member item unique-items) (setf unique-items (append (list item) unique-items))))) unique-items))

(let ((problemA (list (list 'I 'S) (list 'I 'T) (list 'O 'K)))
      (problemB (list (list 'I) (list 'A 'M) (list 'O 'K))))
    (brute-force-guess (first problemA) (second problemA) (third problemA) (find-unique-values problemA) #'print-result)
    (brute-force-guess (first problemB) (second problemB) (third problemB) (find-unique-values problemB) #'print-result))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some preliminary notes for now (I'll add later):

Whenever you need to write `(if n n 2)` or `(if (not n) 2 n)`, you can instead write `(or n 2)`. `or` will take any number of arguments and return either `nil` or the first argument that evaluates to non-`nil`.

---

When working with optional arguments, you can set defaults for them.

```
(defun place-value-to-integer (the-list &OPTIONAL place-value) 
  (let ((place-value (if place-value place-value 1)))
  ...
```

can be written as

```
(defun place-value-to-integer (the-list &OPTIONAL (place-value 1)) 
  ...
```

---

I don't have time to get into the rest right now, but you're using `loop` to `setf` a series of `hash` values, which tells me you could probably simplify it by using a more functional approach (it might be one of the exceptions, but it doesn't feel like one at first glance).

EDIT:

`(if a b nil)` is equivalent to `(when a b)` (and it's good style to use the second over the first).

EDIT2: Ok, wow, hey. That's two hours of my life I won't get back. I wrote up and edited down a pretty ridiculously long piece on my process (if you care, it's [here](http://langnostic.blogspot.com/2011/03/puzzling-with-lisp.html)). Here's how I would tackle a brute-force approach to this problem.

EDIT3: Simplified slightly.

```
(defpackage :cry-fun (:use :cl :cl-ppcre))
(in-package :cry-fun)

(defun digits->number! (&rest digits)
  (apply #'+ (loop for d in (nreverse digits) for i from 0
                   collect (* d (expt 10 i)))))

(defun number->digits (num &optional (pad-to 5))
  (let ((temp num)
        (digits nil))
     (loop do (multiple-value-call 
                   (lambda (rest d) (setf temp rest digits (cons d digits)))
                (floor temp 10))
           until (= pad-to (length digits)))
     digits))

(defun string->terms (problem-string)
  (reverse
   (mapcar (lambda (s) (mapcar (lambda (i) (intern (format nil "~a" i))) 
                   (coerce s 'list)))
           (split " " (string-downcase problem-string)))))

(defmacro solve-for (problem-string)
  (let* ((arg-count (length (remove-duplicates (regex-replace-all " " problem-string ""))))
         (nines (apply #'digits->number! (make-list arg-count :initial-element 9))))
    `(loop for i from 0 to ,nines
           when (apply (solution-fn ,problem-string) (number->digits i ,arg-count))
           collect it)))

(defmacro solution-fn (problem-string)
  (let* ((terms (string->terms problem-string))
         (args (remove-duplicates (apply #'append terms))))
    `(lambda ,args
       (when (= (+ ,@(loop for term in (cdr terms) collect `(digits->number! ,@term)))
                (digits->number! ,@(car terms)))
             (list ,@(mapcan (lambda (i) (list (symbol-name i) i)) args))))))
```

EDIT (by jaresty): adding comments to show example intermediate values for "solution-fn"

```
(defmacro solution-fn (problem-string)
  (let* ((terms (string->terms problem-string)) 
     ;example: (terms ((o k) (i t) (i s)))
         (args (remove-duplicates (apply #'append terms)))) 
         ;example: (args (o k t i s))
    `(lambda ,args
       (when (= (+ ,@(loop for term in (cdr terms) collect `(digits->number! ,@term)))  
                (digits->number! ,@(car terms)))
        ;example: (when (= (+ (i t) (i s)) (o k)
             (list ,@(mapcan (lambda (i) (list (symbol-name i) i)) args))))))
        ;example: (list "o" o "k" k "t" t "i" i "s" s)
```

Comment: Wow, this is a pretty intense solution!  I'm going to need to study it for a while to try and understand how it works.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Can you explain what multiple-value-call does in number->digits?  I'm having some trouble understanding how it works.

Comment: @jaresty: `floor` returns two values: the floored value and the remainder. However when calling it normally, only the first return value will be used. By using `multiple-value-call` both values returned by floor are given to the lambda.

Comment: I linked to a blog post in which I go step-by-step on how I came up with this (it's actually a lot simpler than it looks; most of the complexity in it is introduced because the naive solution I started with performed quite poorly, and the question specifies "as fast as possible"). sepp2k got it on the `multiple-value-call`, and yeah `->` is just part of a name. It's a convention from Scheme where `foo->bar` lets you know that the function takes a `foo` and returns a `bar`.

Comment: Why do you need to use defmacro rather than defun for solve-for and solution-fn?

Comment: How would you use "solve-for" to print out a list of possible solutions?  I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to work with the returning values.  I tried using multiple-value-call, but I only see one answer, "((s 0 i 0 t 0   0 o 0 k 0))", to "is it ok", which doesn't seem right at first glance.

Comment: @jaresty - I used `defmacro` for `solve-for` because it needs to take a variable number of differently named (but specific to the problem) arguments. You could probably define it as a function, but the amount of list slicing I assumed I'd need to do seemed like it would be more complicated (or forced onto the user). I made `solve-for` a macro because I need to pass `solution-fn` a raw string, and I don't know what its value will be at the time I define `solve-for`.

Comment: @jaresty - `solve-fn` currently returns a list of `([letter] [value] ...)` for each possible solution. If you absolutely must print it, way I'd try it here is either by prepending `(format t "~{~a:~a~^, ~}~%"` to `(list ,@(mapcan (lambda (i) (list (symbol-name i) i)) args))))))`. I have to point out though; printing the result rather than returning it severely limits the reusability of the function, and (in this case) doesn't add much to the readability either.

Comment: Ok - I think I need to apologize.  It works great.  The problem seems to have been a makeshift solution I tried to use to replace the strings when I couldn't download cl-ppcre easily (proxy at work - didn't have time to work around it).  Anyway, it seems to work great!  Now I just need some time to try and understand it better.  Thanks again, and I hope it's ok to ask if I still have questions...

Comment: @jaresty - S'ok; I'm happy to keep answering to help clarify. Macros tend to be...difficult the first time. If your work disallows `quicklisp`, `cl-ppcre` should also be installable through `asdf`. In SBCL, evaluate `(require 'asdf) (require 'asdf-install) (asdf-install:install 'cl-ppcre)` (really it should work in any implementation, but I've heard people have some problems with a couple of them). As a last resort, you can get the raw tarball from the [doc-page](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/). PS. pardon the poor editing on the previous comment.

Comment: Is there a better way to debug a function, i.e. peek inside its variables and whatnot, than printing the variables' contents out with format?

Comment: I added comments with my understanding of the intermediate values of solution-fn in an addendum to your post above.  Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @jaresty - I typically test functions piece by piece in the REPL (while I'm constructing them). The main debugging facilities Lisp has are the `trace` and `step` functions. I can't see your addendum; if you edited the post above, I won't be able to see it until a mod approves your edits (you may want to just post a separate answer).

Comment: @jaresty - Yup, you got it. (Only one technical point; because of the way I generate the symbols, they'll actually be `|o| |k| |t| |i| |s|`, but that doesn't change the mechanics of the macroexpansion. `|foo|` just denotes a symbol name with escaped elements).